# SQL group by from multiple tables

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, union

I am using SQL Workbench/J and want to create two columns 'web_sales' and 'app_sales' (see case statements) combining sales data from sales2019 and sales2020 tables. However, my current code is still showing 2 records for a specific item/member combination, based off if data is coming from the 2019 or 2020 table. How can I combine 2019 and 2020 data into one record (see desired output)? The group by statement that exists outside of the subquery does not accomplish this.

```
select *
from (
    select id
      ,item
      ,member
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN platform = 'web' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS web_sales
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN platform = 'app' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS app_sales
    from sales2019
    group by id, item, member
    union
    select id
      ,item
      ,member
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN platform = 'web' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS web_sales
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN platform = 'app' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS app_sales
    from sales2020
    group by id, item, member) A
group by A.id, A.item, A.member 
order by A.item asc;
```

Current Output:

```
id  item    member  web_sales   app_sales
2   desk-blue   y   132.5   374.6
2   desk-blue   n   348.9   2597.9
2   desk-blue   y   753.1   2209.9
2   desk-blue   n   23.3    234.9
3   desk-brown  y   245.4   271.2
3   desk-brown  n   192.4   5295.8
3   desk-brown  n   1.6     776.5
```

Desired Output:

```
id  item    member  web_sales   app_sales
2   desk-blue   y   885.6   2584.5
2   desk-blue   n   372.2   2832.8
3   desk-brown  y   245.4   271.2
3   desk-brown  n   194.0   6072.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the `union all` *before* aggregating:

```
select id, item, member,
       SUM(CASE WHEN platform = 'web' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS web_sales,
       SUM(CASE WHEN platform = 'app' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS app_sales
from ((select id, item, member, platform, revenue
       from sales2019
      ) union all
      (select id, item, member, platform, revenue
       from sales2020
      ) 
     ) s
group by id, item, member
```

Comment: I added the `union all` and am still getting the same output of duplicate item/member combinations.

Comment: @markellefultz20 . . . You don't provide any explanation of the data.  But it would seem that `id` is the id of a member.  And some people change their membership status from one year to the next.